# How to handle focus with puppeteer on Html tags that don't have id, problem with multiple and hidden classes

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, node-modules, puppeteer

I am trying to automate login and scrape for some data, html tags on the web page doesn't have ID only classes. For some reason first time I can focus on input and enter my email address but with similar code it won't type password and I can't figure out why?

I have tried

```
await page.waitForSelector('.login__form-wrap > .form > div:nth-child(1) > .form-group > .form-control')
await page.click('.login__form-wrap > .form > div:nth-child(1) > .form-group > .form-control')
await page.keyboard.type('myemailaddress', {delay: 100});
```

and it's working for email. Then similar code for password not working:

```
await page.waitForSelector('.login__form-wrap > .form > div:nth-child(2) > .form-group > .form-control');
await page.click('.login__form-wrap > .form > div:nth-child(2) > .form-group > .form-control');
await page.keyboard.type('mypassword', {delay: 100});
```

Also tried this way:

```
await page.waitForSelector('input[name=email]');
await page.focus('input[name=email]');
await page.keyboard.type('myemailaddress', {delay: 100});
```

again working, but doing the same for password:

```
await page.waitForSelector('input[name=password]');
await page.focus('input[name=password]');
await page.keyboard.type('myemail', {delay: 100});
```

doesn't work...

Doesn't work means that the password is not typed in input field.

Another solution I tried was:

```
await page.$eval('input[name=password]', el => el.value = "mypassword");
```

That works(the pass was shown), but clicking on login button it said wrong password, and when I typed it manually the same password is correct and page logs me in.

So if someone can point me in right direction of doing it, or how to handle it and show me what I'm doing wrong I would be so thankful.

P.s if you want to play with it the page I'm trying to log in is [here](https://igra.panpivo.hr/prijava)
I already passed the validation and full code is [here](https://pastebin.com/nhFcGGjL)